# Unexpected result while executing terminal command in Jupyter notebook

Tags: shell, jupyter-notebook, grep

Having this cell in the jupyter notebook runs OK:

```
!echo "one two tree"|egrep --color "t[w,r](o|e)"
```

return(as expected): one **two tre**e

while this cell input:

```
!echo "one two tree"|egrep --color "t[w,r](o|e){1,2}"
```

returns nothing on jupyter?!
expected return: one **two tree**

I tried escaping curly braces

```
!echo "one two tree"|egrep --color "t[w,r](o|e)\{1,2\}"
```

still nothing on the return

Comment: Are you on Mac OS?

Comment: yes, on the mac terminal it returns OK

Comment: Try `echo "one two tree"| grep 't[wr][oe]\{1,2\}'`. I think POSIX BRE will work.

Comment: So, how come the same command works fine when it is executed directly from the terminal?

Comment: The POSIX BRE works, but I need the (|) OR option to be explained as well on the notebook

Comment: The problem seems to be with the range/interval/limiting quantifier. `grep -E "t[wr](o|e)(o|e)?"` will work. Also, looks  like the braces needs doubling, try `egrep "t[wr](o|e){{1,2}}"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238015/discussion-between-wiktor-stribizew-and-shlomi-lachmish).

Comment: yes, it worked! (I marked your answer, and comments with +1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using braces that [cause variable expansion](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#shell-assignment) inside the string:

> The line after the bang can call any program installed in the underlying shell, and support variable expansion in the form of `$variable` or `{variable}`.

Hence, to make the braces *literal* you need to double them:

```sh
egrep "t[wr](o|e){{1,2}}"
```